# QGIS EasyPrint alternatives for v2.0.1?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, mapping

I recently upgraded to QGIS v2.0.1 and noticed that the [EasyPrint](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/easyprint/) plugin is not supported for the latest version.  Will this plugin be updated to work in this version, or are there any alternatives for sheet mapping?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, QGIS 2's print composer there is a tab called Atlas Generation, it is how you create map books.